Does 'use warnings' change $^W?
I've been using Getopt::Long and at one point in the code, where I think it should warn(), it doesn't, unless I run with -w.
Upon inspection, the (Getopt::Long) code directly checks the value of $^W.  But I used use warnings;.
That is, the program runs differently with perl program.pl than with perl -w program.pl, even though program.pl contains use warnings; and/or use warnings 'all;
Does checking $^W reflect any use warnings (pragmas?) statements?
One way or the other, the documentation isn't clear.  Unless I've misunderstood.

https://perldoc.perl.org/variables/$%5EW says it's set to true if -w is given. Doesn't mention use warnings; so I doubt that modifies it. The pragma is lexical scope, -w is global, which might have something to do with it.

Also see https://perldoc.perl.org/warnings#What's-wrong-with-w-and-$%5EW for how they interact with the warnings pragma.

use warnings only affects the lexical scope you use it in.  it would have no effect on the code in the module.

is this the use of $^W you are talking about?  https://metacpan.org/release/JV/Getopt-Long-2.58/source/lib/Getopt/Long.pm#L235  that's where it is suppressing warnings when it is about to print a bunch of possibly undef variables for debugging purposes.  it is not checking $^W, it is temporarily clearing it, undoing a possible -w.  I suspect it doesn't just use no warnings there for better support for some archaic version of perl.

As documented, $^W initially shows if -w was used, although it can be modified through assignment.
Note that lack of any mention of use warnings; in that description.
There is a facility to create module-specific warnings which can be checked by the module: warnings::register.
